# What do FIFA 14 position acronyms mean?

Tags: fifa-14

How to distinguish a defender from a left forward... for example? I have not seen a good summary at the web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a list of these on the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football_positions). Here's the ones I remember having seen in Fifa 14. They are always color-coded to show which area of the game they belong to. For the center positions the left and right seems to refer to the current formation. I.e. a player cannot be a LCB. He's a CB on his bio, but he is playing the LCB position.

Goalkeeper: Orange

- GK: Goalkeeper

Defense: Yellow

- CB: Center-back
- LCB: Left center-back
- RCB: Right center-back
- LB: Left-back (Full-back)
- RB: Right-back (Full-back)

Midfield: Green

- CM : Centre midfield
- LDM: Left defensive midfield
- LAM: Left attacking midfield
- RDM: Right defensive midfield
- RAM: Right attacking midfield
- CDM: Centre defensive midfield
- CAM: Centre attacking midfield
- LM : Left midfield
- RM : Right midfield

Attack: Blue

- ST: Striker
- CF: Center forward
- LW: Left winger
- RW: Right winger